# how to create a list view with textview and increase n decrease button?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Adapter class

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;



    /*public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }*/
    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    }
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        name.setText(list.get(position));
        final TextView milkCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.milkcount);
        if (milkCount.getText().toString().trim() == null) {
            milkCount.setText("0");
        }
        ImageView increment = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        ImageView decrement = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_item);
        increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(milkCount.getText().toString().trim());
                a = a + 1;
                milkCount.setText("" + a);
            }
        });
        decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(milkCount.getText().toString().trim());
            if (a == 0) {
                a = 0;
            } else {
                a = a - 1;
            }
            milkCount.setText("" + a);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Main  Activity

```
public class DailyScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements 



AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


///Description
ImageView add, edit;
MyCustomAdapter adapter1;
Button ok;
Button next2;

final Context context = this;
ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}

public void setArrayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

private ArrayList<String> arrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.daily_listview);

    //initialization
    add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
    edit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next2);

    String items[] = {"toned milk"};
    //this.setArrayList((ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(items));
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(arrayList, this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DailyScreen.this, SupplierActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DailyScreen.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Enter new Milk");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);// to prevent the user when he click  any where in the screen
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();

            //initialization for edit text
            final EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pro);
            String data = editText.getText().toString();
```

here is the code what I have tried I want to have a text view n button in list view which will increase n decrease with respect to the text view .  when I'm trying adding a new items it setting 0 in above all item .so all the item I have added before I have to start from 0.

so please help me out

[image]

```
            //button initialization
            Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String data = editText.getText().toString();
                    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                        arrayList.add(data);
                        adapter1=null;
                        adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(arrayList,DailyScreen.this);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product name is :" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();// to   refresh with update one

                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(DailyScreen.this, "Please enter the data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });

        }

    });



}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    View k=view;

}
// to initialize  Context menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);


}


//checking to delete the item and refreshing the items
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:
            arrayList.remove(info.position);
            //to refresh the list view
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: hello, can you explain Properly What exactly you going to make?? Any Example ?? if you see it somewhere?? Because I cant understand what your requirement

Comment: @VishalHalani i want to create a list view where i will having the item and quantity box  which will be managed by add and subtract button ....problem I'm facing is when I'm adding a new item it is reverting all the quantity of  above item into zero value ....so please help me

Comment: Hello Jyoti.. What problem you'r facing?

Comment: @PiyushGupta problem I'm facing is when I'm adding a new item it is reverting all the quantity of above item into zero value ....

Comment: you should maintain tag for those buttons.

Comment: i have tried can u solve it for me as I have tried from last 9 days still not able to do it @PiyushGupta

Comment: @jyotiswain when click on add ans decrease button it work. i mean it change Quantity?

Comment: @jyotiswain You can mail me

Comment: @jyotiswain i think you just store Milk name in array list right..? you did not store quantity.

Comment: i think you have to make one model class with milk name and quantity. and one constructor with  milkname and quantity.then create getter setter of both .and when add new milk name then by default store quantity 0.in contructor

Comment: @jyotiswain make one array list with model type so whn you add new milk name you put that model in this list and pass it in adapter

Comment: and yeah when user click on + button you just get that item position model class from list and set quantity with +1 with setter

Comment: It is the same suggestion i made below in my answer and comment :-)

Comment: hey can u come on team view and help me out@VishalHalani

Comment: @Davidea no not able to do

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not mapping the quantity from your model object but always from a new text view that is generated when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I also see several small programming mistakes like

- `private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` while in the constructor you initiliaze `list`
- `if (milkCount.getText().toString().trim() == null)`
- `adapter1=null;` and then `adapter1 = new ...`
- `list.get(position)` while you have declared `getItem(position)` that does that.
- `final Context context = this;` useless.

and I can continue... :-)

Comment: Instead of String you should create a custom model object containing the ID, the title, the quantity, and something else probably.
So you initialize the list with these model items, then in the binding when you invoke `getItem()`, you have your model object with all your data.

Can I suggest you to have a look at my adapter library for RecyclerView? the project is https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter, but you are going to change everything and abandon the ListView.

Comment: can u help me out @Davidea